# In which control should I place my controls to be able to hide/show them?

Tags: android, layout

I have an activity with the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout  
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button ....
            <EditText ....
            //..........
```

I want to place a group of controls into the 2nd LinearLayout so that I'll be able to hide them all at once when I click the button. I suppose I should wrap them in one more LinearLayout and hide/show it when I click the button.

I've tried that and got an error saying basically it wasn't allowed. Did I do anything wrong with that? If not, what should I use instead?

Comment: paste the entire code that you've tried and got error

Comment: please post your error and code completely

Comment: please post your java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to hide/show your layout containing some views, on button click:

```
  LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id); 

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
        if(ll.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
       {
        ll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    //use View.GONE, if required
       }
       else
       {
        ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }

      }    
    }
```

Comment: then please clarify, what's problem you're facing

Comment: the layout, the control.